# how to access third party website

Tags: php

```
//$out = fopen($localfilename, 'wb'); 
$url ="some https site name";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sar:pas"); 
echo curl_exec($ch); 
return $ch;
//curl_close($ch); 
//fclose($out);
```

i tried with code for automatic login to thirdparty website

```
$url="some url name";
```

in the username password i used `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sar:pas");`
i alread fetech the username password from database table 
but i am not using file & i commented the belowed two lines in the code

```
$out = fopen($localfilename, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
```

i have tried the code its not working in https site
help me in this senorio

by
saravanamuthu

Comment: **WHY** is it "not working"? Any errors? What response do you get?

Answer (score 0):

To access HTTPS websites, you would need to set the following cURL option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

HTH.

---

**EDIT:** Here's a helpful site: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/ that you get by googling "curl https"

Comment: hi thanks for your line but its still not logged into the third party website. i can see it out the helpful site

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to understand you.